# Transistor help

Tags: transistors

I've read some info on transistor about how it works. So let's say I savaged a receiver from a remote control car which generates 1.2v output from the receiver when signal is transmitted from the controller, would my circuit works? Still a beginner in electronics, forgive me for my bad circuit drawing.

[image]

**EDIT** - I think I may understand a bit now, if it's positioned the way on the left, would it work? Also, what are the difference between the left and the right?

[image]

Comment: How did you measure the receiver output? Although possible it seems a bit low.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't..
I'm just trying to ask whether if transistor can be used this way, to turn on a 12v load circuit, with 1.2v, or similar..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have drawn is an emitter follower circuit to power your load and, if your load was normally activated by about half a volt then your circuit will work.

However, it seems you want the full 12 volts to be applied to your load and this means voltage amplification. Try researching common emitter load control circuits.

I'll draw a picture in a while but I'm on android at the moment and that is impossible for me!

### EDIT (simple analogy alert)

This is overly simple but hopefully demonstrates what happens (or what you need to do) when using a BJT to switch a load: -

[image]

In this circuit the BJT's emitter is grounded to 0V and any voltage applied to the base (provided it is above a certain threshold ~0.7V) will start to conduct a reasonable amount of current from collector to emitter. You can fully control small to medium loads when they are placed in the collector circuit.

Can you see that if you placed the load in the emitter AND your control voltage is only 1.2 volts, the voltage across the load cannot ever become 12V.

Comment: Would it change anything if I position the load before the collector?
If not, then how could I make the circuit work??

Comment: If you put the load between collector and 12V supply you have the common-emitter circuit I allude to in my answer. This stands a much better chance of working on light to medium (<500mA) loads. Because the emitter is tied directly to 0V, the base looks like a diode to ground so you need a base series resistor to prevent hundreds of mA flowing into the base - maybe try 100 ohms.

Comment: So if the load is between collector and 12V supply, it would get 12V when the transistor is "on" (not sure what to call it)? Why couldn't it be used to high loads? Resistor on base, that's to prevent over current from the 12v supply and also from the 1.2v receiver, am I right? Sorry for so much question, still a total beginner.

Comment: High loads - the BJT cannot be made to have 0 ohms on-resistance and so loads that take a lot of current cause appreciable volt drop across the BJT when activated. For high load currents a MOSFET is a far better choice - almost similar performance to a relay contact. Base resistor as you said.

Comment: I still couldn't quite understand. Designed another circuit and added a new picture, can you help me check the circuit again and tell me if that would work?

Comment: The picture on the left would work but don't forget the base resistor. With the load in the emitter the max voltage it can see is 1.2 volts minus about 0.7 volts due to the base-emitter junction acting as a diode.

Comment: Thanks so much, I finally understand now.
One last question, for the base resistor, which current is it actually resisting? The current from the Receiver, current from the 12 V supply, or both?

Comment: It's input current it is defining. If base emitter needs 0.7 volts and input is 1.7 volts then resistor has to lose 1 volt. If base current is 10mA then R is 100 ohm.